# Why are the rails errors not showing up?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have this form_for

```
<%= form_for([@post, @post.comments.build]) do |f| %>

<% if @post.errors.any? %>
   <div id="error_explanation">
     <ul>
     <% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
       <li><%= msg %></li>
     <% end %>
     </ul>
   </div>
<% end %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :body %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :body %>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You are not seeing errors because you are creating a new object for the form every time it is loaded:

```
@post.comments.build
```

You should add an instance variable to your controller and use that in the form instead:

```
@comment = @post.comments.build

<%= form_for([@post, @comment]) do |f| %>
```

Comment: If you're creating a comment, then it should post to the comments controller create action.